# Auto layout on UIImageView (landscape, portrait) alignment issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, constraints

I am using auto layout on UIImageView in UITableViewCell. The constraints are leading, bottom, top, height and width. UIImageView frame size is (134,75). Images load from url. Content mode is aspecttofit.
My problem is that when image is in landscape mode, it looks good but in portrait, it will display in the centre of the cell. image width is equal to cell width and I want to display portrait picture left align not in the centre of the screen. Also image width for portrait should not be same for landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to delete the width and height constraint and put leading, trailing, top and bottom.

Comment: It's not working but thanks for the answer. After implementing trailing portrait image looks good but not landscape

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the leading, trailing, top and bottom aligned to the edges of the cell then,

Try changing the UIImageView contentMode to

```
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

OR

```
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
```

Comment: Its not working, thanks bro. I am using estimated height for row, my row becomes giant after implementing fill